# ngx-datatable-How to check/uncheck header checkbox on button click

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

In ngx-datatable,how to check/uncheck header column(headerCheckboxable)( column with a checkbox) on click of button.

When I click on the cancel button, my all rows get deselected but header checkbox remains selected.

Comment: Can you please share a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) replicating this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could reset the `selected` property of your ngx-datatable. This will deselect all rows including the header checkbox.
Here is a small code snippet to demonstrate this:

```js
@ViewChild('mytable') table: DatatableComponent;

selectedRows = [];

onSelect({ selected }) {
    this.selectedRows.splice(0, this.selectedRows.length);
    this.selectedRows.push(...selected);
}

onSomeActionToDeselectAllRows() {
  this.onSelect({selected: []});
  this.table.selected = [];
}
```

```html
<ngx-datatable #mytable
  [selected]="selectedRows"
  (select)="onSelect($event)">
```

Comment: Seems like this will de-select all already checked box no matter the page. Is it possible to just specifically de-select the checkbox in the header?